# Binary tree traversal causes stack overflow

Tags: c, recursion, tree, stack-overflow, traversal

So I'm making a binary search tree implemented through arrays (if parent's index is i, then left child's index is (i * 2 + 1), and right child's index is (i * 2 + 2).

Whenever I'm trying to traverse the tree (pre-orderly), I'm getting a stack overflow during the 3rd pre-order function call.

Here's my code for pre-order function:

```
void traversePreOrder(Tree tree, int index)
{
    printf("%d\n", index); //debug
    if (tree.data[index].accNumber != 0) //all .accNumber values are initialized as 0
                                   // at the start of the program to mark empty nodes.
    {
        printf("printing: %d\n", index); //debug
        printNode(tree.data[index]);

        if (tree.data[index * 2 + 1].accNumber != 0)
        {
            printf("will print: %d\n", index * 2 + 1); //debug
            traversePreOrder(tree, index * 2 + 1);
        }

        if (tree.data[index * 2 + 2].accNumber != 0)
        {
            printf("will print: %d\n", index * 2 + 2); //debug
            traversePreOrder(tree, index * 2 + 2);
        }
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Here is the output of pre-order traversal:

```
0
printing: 0
User: Dumbledore
Account number: 53167
Account type: public
Account balance: 4597.54
Is account in debt? Yes

will print: 1
1
printing: 1
User: Stark
Account number: 13497
Account type: private
Account balance: 1549.50
Is account in debt? No

will print: 3

Process returned  255 (0xFF)   execution time : 5.856 s
Press any key to continue.
```

The tree is supposed to look like:

```
(only accNumber values)
                    53167
                  /       \
              13457      74310
                 \       /   \
               43158  71401  79473
                /      /       \
             14741   69690    99751
```

Thank you for your help.

---

**Update**

Changing maximum tree capacity from 1000 to 50 somehow solved the problem. If somebody could explain why, that would be nice.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that you are reading beyond initialized data within your array and therefore recursing forever.  As a quick test, can you make sure that your whole tree.data[] structure is cleared to 0 (so that a read into data not yet written returns a 0 and fails gracefully) so that this can be ruled out?

Comment: Right after I create the tree I use this function:
    void initializeTree(Tree * tree)
    {
        if (tree == NULL)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TREE_CAPACITY; i++)
        {
            tree->data[i].accNumber = 0;
       }
    }

Comment: You cannot probe `data` unless the index used is *known* to be within the limits of `data`'s magnitude. Just because you have a node in your array doesn't mean both its kids are there as well. Ex: your posted tree is storable in an array of 16 nodes, Ask yourself what your code does when you recurse to examine the *children* of index 15. Checking `tree.data[index * 2 + 1].accNumber != 0` isn't enough. Before that you need to know that `index * 2 + 1` is within `0..(n-1)`, where `n` is the magnitude of `data` in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig Maximum capacity of the tree is 1000 nodes, so in this case it shouldn't be a problem (or am I not interpreting your comment right?). Thank you for the tip though, I'll add that to the code.

Comment: @HarisVitunskas that was somewhat the point. Whether there is or is not space for those children, eventually you *can* reach a node that cannot *have* children, much less children with `0`, simply because there is no space in the array for there to be any, and your posted code makes *no* affordances to prevent invoking UB in that case. Something such as  `if (index >= tree.maxnodes) return;` assuming such a member exists, at the top of the function would alleviate most of that problem. It would also remove the need for the embedded `if` conditions.

Comment: There is is absolutly no information in your question about the absolut tree capacity. How do you expect anyone to explain?

Answer (score 1):

You state that:

> all .accNumber values are initialized as 0 at the start of the program
>   to mark empty nodes.

This is not a strong enough criterion for the recursion to stop.

If you want to be explicit you should make an upperbound to the index and make sure you don't exceed it. For example: if `tree.size` iz the number of nodes in the tree, you should also chack before each step of the recursion, like this:

```
    int left_child_idx = index * 2 + 1;
    if (tree.data[left_child_idx].accNumber != 0 && left_child_idx < tree.size)
    {
        printf("will print: %d\n", index * 2 + 1); //debug
        traversePreOrder(tree, index * 2 + 1);
    }
```

Or, if you do not want to do this, you should make sure, that there is two terminating leaf with 0 `accNumber` for **all** your last nodes.

In this datastructure that actually means that the second half of your `data` array should solely consist of such terminating leafs.

Looks ugly, but I hope you see it:

```
                      53167
                  /           \
              13457             74310
             /   \            /       \
            0      43158     71401     79473
          /  \     /   \     /    \      /  \
         0    0   14741  0  69690  0    0   99751
        /\    /\   /\    /\   /\   /\   /\   /\
       0  0  0  0 0  0  0  0 0  0 0  0 0  0 0  0
```

And as an array:

```
[53167, 13457, 74310, 0, 43158, 71401, 79473, 0, 0, 14741, 0, 69690, 0, 0, 99751,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

There is 31 element, 99751 is the 15th. Would any of the second half be non-zero, you would get an overflow.